# Update data using vue-resource

Tags: javascript, vue-component, vue-resource, vue.js

In my Vue component I have the following data:

```
data() {
    return {
        revenueChart: '',
        limit: 12,
        labels: '',
        datasets: ''
    }
},
```

Also, there is one method that uses **vue-resource** to fetch the data:

```
    fetchData() {
        this.$http.get(this.url, {params: {limit: this.limit}}).then(function (response) {
            this.labels = Object.keys(response.data);
            this.datasets = Object.values(response.data);
        });
    },
```

As you can see, this method should update `labels` and `datasets`, but for some reason they are still empty strings (`''`), they still have the default values.

For example, I also have the following method that should use these data to generate a graph:

```
    generateGraph() {
        var data = {
            labels: this.labels, // HERE
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "Revenue",
                    backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                    borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                    data: this.datasets // AND HERE
                }
            ]
        };

        var ctx = this.$refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
        this.revenueChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: data
        });
    },
```

Finally:

```
    mounted() {
        this.fetchData();
        console.log(this.labels); // STILL EMPTY !
        console.log(this.datasets); // STILL EMPTY !
        this.generateGraph();
    },
```

My graph is empty, after using the `fetchData` method `this.labels` and `this.datasets` are still empty.

Here is the complete component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <label>How Many Days?</label>
        <select v-model="limit">
            <option v-for="n in 12">{{ n }}</option>
        </select>
        <canvas ref="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            url: ''
        },

        data() {
            return {
                revenueChart: '',
                limit: 12,
                labels: '',
                datasets: ''
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            this.fetchData();
            console.log(this.labels); // STILL EMPTY !
            console.log(this.datasets); // STILL EMPTY !
            this.generateGraph();
        },

        methods: {
            fetchData() {
                this.$http.get(this.url, {params: {limit: this.limit}}).then(function (response) {
                    this.labels = Object.keys(response.data);
                    this.datasets = Object.values(response.data);
                });
            },

            generateGraph() {
                var data = {
                    labels: this.labels,
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            label: "Revenue",
                            backgroundColor: "rgba(75,192,192,0.4)",
                            borderColor: "rgba(75,192,192,1)",
                            data: this.datasets
                        }
                    ]
                };

                var ctx = this.$refs.canvas.getContext('2d');
                this.revenueChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'line',
                    data: data
                });
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: maybe try using the nextTick function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that scope has been changed inside `vue-resource`, due to which it is not updating `vue` data variables, try following:

```
fetchData() {
    var self = this
    this.$http.get(this.url, {params: {limit: this.limit}}).then(function (response) {
        self.labels = Object.keys(response.data);
        self.datasets = Object.values(response.data);
    });
},
```

An alternate way can be to use `this.$set`, as it is described in the documentation [here](https://github.com/pagekit/vue-resource/blob/master/docs/http.md#example).

```
fetchData() {
    this.$http.get(this.url, {params: {limit: this.limit}}).then(function (response) {
        this.$set(labels, Object.keys(response.data))
        this.$set(datasets, Object.values(response.data))
    });
},
```

---

### Edited

```
mounted() {
    this.fetchData();
    console.log(this.labels); // STILL EMPTY !
    console.log(this.datasets); // STILL EMPTY !
    this.generateGraph();
},
```

You will not be able to see the data here, as `fetchData` is an async function, so data will not be populated by the time these console log will be executed, but you can use these variables in the template, and they will render as soon as data is populated, or probably you can use [nextTick](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick) as suggested in the comments to console log the data.

Comment: I've tried both, it does not work, the problem is the same.

Comment: @PeraMika Can you see `response ` getting populating in `$http.get`  by logging, does it need JSON parsing?

Comment: That is fine.. it probably has something to do with `nextTick` (as **claudios** suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40796499/update-data-using-vue-resource/40797075?noredirect=1#comment68814932_40796499).

Comment: @PeraMika yes you are right, it will not print immediately as you are trying to do, as `fetchData` is a async method. updated the answer.